# Unable to boot Into Windows 7 after Ubuntu 10.04 update

Tags: 10.04, windows-7, update-manager, bootloader

I'm running a dual boot Windows 7 / Ubuntu 10.04 system.  I ran the Ubuntu update last night, and today when I tried to boot into Windows 7, it goes straight to the windows recovery on my Acer 5517 laptop.  I've spent the entire day trying to resolve this with no success.  I used my Windows 7 Recovery Disk to reset the mbr, but that didn't help.  The system was working perfectly prior to the update.  It appears that now Grub is pointing to the recovery partition rather than the primary partition.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.  I don't relish the idea of reformatting and starting from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

I have found a solution which is more of a workaround than a fix. I installed [startupmanager](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/startupmanager) which is a GRUB GUI. When I ran it there was an additional (new) choice on the menu, one which actually said

```
Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda2).
```

Selecting this option starts Windows 7 as it should. Prior to the Ubuntu update that started this problem, the menu item that started Win7 was listed as

```
Windows Vista (loader) (on /dev/sda1)
```

Comment: don't forget to accept this as your accepted answer by clicking the checkmark under the number, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are using GRUB2. There is an excellent guide on [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows).

Comment: Christoper, thanks for trying to help.  I had already been to the site you suggested.  I've literally spent the entire day trying to recover from this problem.  I finally came up with a solution, which is more of a workaround than a fix.  See my additional comments. BTW, the help.ubuntu.com section on grub needs to be updated because it mostly deals with the legacy grub.